# Pressed CTRL-C to stop update, then updated GAE. Now: Transaction already in progress, but rollback not possible

Tags: google-app-engine

I was just updating my webapp on AppEngine but it got stuck while compiling. I pressed CTRL-C to abort, and appcfg.py gave me some output that it would rollback the update. Since this had happened multiple times today and I knew that there was an update, I downloaded the newest Python SDK, deleted the old one and tried to update again. Now it keeps telling me that there is still a transaction going on by myself, but whenever I try to rollback using `~/google_appengine/appcfg.py update rollback [my-app-directory]` it says that the Directory does not contain an rollback.yaml file. I am absolutely sure I did not delete any file in that directory. 
Is there any way to solve this without having to use a new ID?

Answer (score 1):

`rollback` is a command like `update`. You need to rollback the previous update before launching a new update:

```
appcfg.py rollback [my-app-directory]
```

then

```
appcfg.py update [my-app-directory]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the rollback does not find an rollback.yaml file. I don't know why exactly because I'm pretty sure I used the command correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what to do myself. I set the version in the app.yaml file to 2 and was then able to update it. Next thing I did was to go to appengine.google.com, chose "Versions" on the left and selected the new one as default.